# how to file encrypting faster

Tags: java, android, encryption

My file encryption is very slow! 2 minutes for 70 Mb. I use [this library](https://github.com/cirorizzo/JealousSky) and class for Encrypting files. It works but it's very slow. E.g. for a file .mp4 (70Mb) the encryption takes 2 minutes.

I searched a lot in this site and internet but couldn't find a fast way. My encrypt class is JealousSky :

[JealousSky.class](https://github.com/cirorizzo/JealousSky/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/cirorizzo/JealousSky.java)

My code for Encryption is this :

```
try {
        jealousSky.initialize(
                "longestPasswordEverCreatedInAllTheUniverseOrMore",
                "FFD7BADF2FBB1999");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(listFiles[position]);
        jealousSky.encryptToFile(is,listFiles[position].getParent()+"/"+EncName);
        givenFile.delete();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit :

**Solution**

in JealousSky.class and encrypt method must to change (getEncryptInputStream) to (getDecryptFromCipherInputStream)

finaly 2min decreased to 12s

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55327793/edit) your post to list out what hardware/OS version you are testing on. Also state if you tried on different devices.

Comment: what encryption algorithm are you using? what key length?

Comment: Use buffered streams for input and output.

Comment: You need to get better at choosing libraries. JealousSky says it's "an efficient library", but it also says it's "still in progress", and it hasn't been updated for three years. It has only two contributors, 29 commits, no branches or pull requests, and hardly even any open issues. In short, a dead library, used by almost no one. Not a good choice for encryption.

Comment: @DavidS Do you have a better library for encrypting files?

Comment: JCE is such a library and it is already part of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what kind of encryption you want, there will be different speed for different specifications.

Regardless, I suggest you to use other encryption libraries that are better written and maintained, I have no experience with the library you named, but you can consider the native [Java security components](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html) like [Java Cryptography Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html), if that can't do the job for you, then research further on other third-party libraries.

Comment: that Library use AES bytes[16]

Comment: @fazel Normally the encryption itself should not take so long. As well I see that JealousSky library is doing terrible job with memory management (getEncryptInputStream), seems it's a pretty lousy implementation. Just use pure Java crypto (if you can do that properly).

Comment: that's exactly my point, thanks for clarifying, you put it better than I did.

Comment: @gusto2 ♥♥♥♥♥  yesssss ,, i changed the (getEncryptInputStream) and use from (getDecryptFromCipherInputStream) for both (encrypt / decrypt) ,,, finaly 2min decreased to 12s